# Can I sync contents of external harddisk with Megasync?

Tags: hard-drive, sync, usb-storage, cloud-storage, mega

I just added a new sync and the local folder is located on a USB external hard disk.
What will happen when I disconnect the hard disk from the computer? Will Mega keep the files in the cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experiences with Megasync for Mac 1.0.39:

1. *When you disconnect the drive:* Megasync will stop syncing folders that were on that drive. No files are removed from the local machine or from the cloud.
2. *When the drive is connected again:* Megasync will not enable syncing automatically. You'll have to manually enable syncing of folders on the external disk.

One annoyance I discovered was that Megasync might lock your external drive and prevent ejecting of that drive. In this case a manual disabling of sync is not needed.

I did not find any documentation regarding this matter from Mega website. Therefore I cannot confirm that my experiences apply to other users.